# python script in jupyter notebook sagemaker, GLIBC and tensorflow error

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker, glibc

I am trying to run a python script in sagemaker and it's giving me error:---- /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tflite_runtime/_pywrap_tensorflow_interpreter_wrapper.so)

without run of my python script in github model

Comment: It looks like you are facing an issue related to the version of GLIBC (GNU C Library) required by tensorflow lite on SageMaker. 


**error:---- /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tflite_runtime/_pywrap_tensorflow_interpreter_wrapper.so)**The error message indicates that the version of GLIBC installed on your SageMaker instance is older than the version required by TensorFlow Lite.